# Emphasize peaks in audio data

Tags: javascript, algorithm, audio, data-visualization

I am trying to create a music visualizer, and have made good progress, but I am stuck on trying to emphasize the peaks in the visualization. Here is a frame of a song on my visualizer
[image]

and here is the same frame of the song, but the video where the actual visualizer is:
[image]

I have an algorithm to smooth it out, like this:
[image]

but what can I do to get the result as shown in that video? I have looked all over the web to find a solution, and have came close with this algorithm,

```
function ms(array) {
    var newArr = [];
    var m = math.mean(array);
    var s = math.std(array);
    for (var i in array) {
        if (array[i] - m > 2 * s) {
            newArr[i] = array[i];
        } else {
            newArr[i] = array[i] / 2;
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

but it still doesnt work well. How can I go about this, and will I need the volume data for the audio as well?

Comment: When I look at your images, it makes me feel that there should be a Math.pow operation on your frame data. Try this (assuming your each frame data value in range 0 to 1 `newArray = dataArray.map(v => Math.pow(v, 1 - v))`

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak I get this http://i.imgur.com/dJMoLmz.png

Comment: what is your data value range ? 0 to 1 or 0 to 255. if it is 0 to 255 then you should calculate like `newArray = dataArray.map(v => Math.pow(v=v/255, 1 - v) * 255)`

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak 0-255, but now I get this http://imgur.com/a/G7jeW, it still doesnt have that middle peak

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong tree trying to scale the data. I would guess they're doing something different in the processing than you are. Is this an Nth octave analyzer?  They might be taking each point and running it through some meter ballistics algorithm or something like that.

Comment: Do you have any idea what algorithms or functions visualizers like those @jaket would be using?

Comment: They are based on industry standards.  IEC 61672 for example. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_level_meter for some pointers